# Is there a way to display/use the user input to perform various functions like creating a table

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very new to programming and I trying to create an image that will be customizable on the basis of user preference. I figured out how to get the input but I don't know how to extract/use it. In the following code I'm trying to display the input but I'm unable to.

```
<form>
Title:
<input type="text" input id="title" value=''autofocus> 
<br><br>
Primary Function Color
<input type="color" name="pfColor">
<br><br>
Secondary function Color
<input type="color" name="sfColor">
<br><br>
Neutral Color
<input type="color" name="nColor">
<br><br>
<input type=submit onclick="Initial_Display()"> 
<input type=reset>
</form>
<script>
    function Initial_Display(){
    var Title=document.getElementById("title").innerHTML;
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get you started try the following:
(I have changed it as little as possible, enough for you to see something happening).

```
<form>
    Title:
    <input type="text" id="title" autofocus> 
    <br><br>
    Primary Function Color
    <input type="color" name="pfColor">
    <br><br>
    Secondary function Color
    <input type="color" name="sfColor">
    <br><br>
    Neutral Color
    <input type="color" name="nColor">
    <br><br>
    <input type="button" onclick="Initial_Display()" value="click me!"> 
    <input type="reset">
</form>

<script>
    function Initial_Display(){
    var Title=document.getElementById("title").value;
    alert(Title);
    };
</script>
```

1) changed the 'submit' button to an ordinary button (type="button"), I did this because otherwise the page gets submitted and the onclick doesn't have a chance to do anything.

2) var Title=document.getElementById("title").value; - here I've changed it so that you get the input's 'value', not the innerHTML.

3) I've added an alert() to the script at the bottom so that you can see the value we get.

4) You don't need to set the first input field's value (value='') because it is empty by default anyway when you load the page.

Now just write something in the top input field and press the 'click me!' button.

I hope that this helps you a little.